# HTML Source with JQuery or JavaScript after edit

Tags: javascript, html

Im using this to capture the HTML source for a single html page.
It works good except for one thing.
After entering values into my html page, when I do the capture it only captures the page without the edited values.

Any Ideas please.

```
var getDocTypeAsString = function () {
    var node = document.doctype;
    return node ? "<!DOCTYPE "
    + node.name
    + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
    + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '')
    + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
    + '>\n' : '';
};




 function getPageHTML() {
     //    alert( "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>" );

     console.log(getDocTypeAsString() + document.documentElement.outerHTML);    
 }
```

and the call from the button

```
<div class="no-print">
    <div class="buttonBar">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Print" onClick="window.print()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Save" onClick="getPageHTML()">
    </div>
</div>
```

The editing values will come from similar fields like this
So I would like to capture the edited 'PastMedicalHistory' as-well

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='cell100'>
        <div class='table'>
            <div class='cell100 content'>
                <textarea id='PMH' class='basicTextArea PMHText' name="PastMedicalHistory"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you editing values in provided code ?

Comment: why is jquery in the tags when you dont use it?

Comment: There was a comment provided the solution on a fiddlejs page a few minutes ago. Why was it removed? It used jquery but could be rewritten without jquery calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that seems to work fine, but Im not that great of an expert to judge this on possible limitations

keep a watch over items like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var isDirty = false;
    $("textarea").on("change", function() {
        isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
    });

    $("input").on("change", function() {
        isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
    });
});
```

call for the source of the new html like this

```
function getPageHTML() {
    console.log( "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?

The statement `document.documentElement.outerHTML` will take the HTML itself as rendered.

The values of the input elements are filled in afterwards, so not visible via `outerHTML`.

You could run through the elements, inspect them and populate the DOM.

What would be for the best, though is to describe what are you trying to achieve and put the full code example on codepen or similar.

Comment: Okay, fair point. I want to capture the full and edited html page to save as a blog in a DB. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, this *easy* way. You're getting the same as looking "source code" from your browser.

Use jQuery or JS to parse document input values.

Then *reinject* it in your getDocTypeAsString